# Count wildcard date in Text String

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am looking for a formula to Count Specific date in Text String. My answers work with words, but if I use wildcards it doesn't work. W33 is the sample text below. I would expect a result of 2 but I am getting 0. I am using Excel 2010.

I have tried the following:

```
=(LEN(W33)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE((W33),("????-??-?? ??:??:??.??? "),"")))/LEN("????-??-?? ??:??:??.??? ")
```

Sample Text in one cell:

```
[(updated, will clear)swya (C - HF )(2022-04-15 07:37:08.826 )][(does not have details on the transaction, to advise on the same)swya (C - HF )(2022-04-12 06:57:12.440 )]
```

Answer (score 2):

You tagged Excel 2010, Excel 2007. In that case try:

```
=SUM(--IFERROR(1=SEARCH("????-??-?? ??:??:??.???",MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))),0))
```

And confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, wildcards only work in certain functions with Excel.

Wildcards work with all of the following functions:

- SUMIF, SUMIFS
- COUNTIF, COUNTIFS
- AVERAGEIF, AVERAGEIFS
- VLOOKUP
- HLOOKUP ('<>' won't work with this)
- MATCH ('<>' won't work with this)

([Source](https://www.excelawesome.com/12-excel-wildcard-examples-you-need-to-know/))

If your data is consistently in that format, then I would target 'swya' or '(C-HF)'. If not you can try Text to Columns and then use COUNTIF within that range, however, it isn't very automated.

Answer (score 1):

One option, assuming access to the `LET` and `SEQUENCE` functions:

`=LET(ξ,"????-??-?? ??:??:??.??? ",COUNT(SEARCH(ξ,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),LEN(ξ)))))`